# How do I check if email and company name doesn't already exist in mysql database

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could help(sorry I know this subject has been brought up before)

I have a sign up form I want to make sure that the company and email address doesn't exist before it is submitted.

I am grateful for any help.

Oh my table name is R_TABLE and the field is COMPANY
Oh my table name is U_TABLE and the field is EMAIL

```
    <?
    session_start();
    //ignore this -->$email = $_POST['email'] ;

    //error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    //ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

    //Connect to Database
    include('includes/dbconn.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <title>Sign Up Form</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />



   <link href="eps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <div class="header2">
   </div>

   //VALIDATES FIELDS

     <script language="javascript">

     function validateForm()
     {

 var x=document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
 var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
 {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
 } 
if (document.forms["form1"]["email"].value != document.forms["form1"]  ["email2"].value) {
    alert("Email addresses do not match");
    return false;
 }


    {
    var x=document.forms["form1"]["companyName"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Please enter your company name.");
    return false;
    }




    }
    }

    </script>






    </head>


    <body background="images/background.gif" repeat >
    <table width="1101" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <br/> <br/>



 <p align="center" class="SignUpText">Sign Up Form</p>
     <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="TableBorder">
     <tr>
     <td>
     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="signup.php" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input name="a" type="hidden" id="a" value="signup" />
    <input name="group" type="hidden" id="group" />

    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="MainText">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="auto-style4" style="height: 40px"><strong>
<span class="auto-style5">Personal Information</span><br/>
    </tr>

     //COMPANY NAME

    <tr>
    <td width="25%">Company Name</td>
    <td style="width: 2%">*</td>
    <td width="25%"><label>

 <input name="companyName" type="text" class="auto-style3" id="companyName" size="35" /></label></td>

     <td style="width: 2%"><a href="#" class="hintanchor" onMouseover="showhint('Please enter your registered company name.', this, event, '150px')">?</a></td>


      //EMAIL

      <td>
  <input name="email" type="text" class="auto-style3" id="email" size="40" /></td>
      <tr>
      <td>Re-enter Email Address</td>
      <td style="width: 2%">*</td>
      <td>
  <input name="email2" type="text" class="auto-style3" id="email2" size="40" />    </td>

      //SUBMIT

      <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up" />
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>


Here is part of the class that adds new users, the email actually is added to contactEmail field , company is added to companyname within the database which I need to check if it doesn't already have the email and company name stored

function addmember($companyname,  $licencenumber,$companyNumber,$vatNumber,$address1,$address2,$address3,$town,$county,$postcode,$firstname,$surname,$email,$phone,$training,$norepairs,$logo,$repairtype,$repairgroup,$mode)
{

    $ref = "REP";
    $licencenumber = "TEST";

    $query = "INSERT INTO r_table VALUES ";
    $query.= "(NULL,";
    $query.= "\"$ref\",";
    $query.= "\"$companyname\",";
    $query.= "\"$licencenumber\",";
    $query.= "\"$companyNumber\",";
    $query.= "\"$vatNumber\",";
    $query.= "\"$address1\",";
    $query.= "\"$address2\",";
    $query.= "\"$address3\",";
    $query.= "\"$town\",";
    $query.= "\"$county\",";
    $query.= "\"$postcode\",";
    $query.= "\"$firstname\",";
    $query.= "\"$surname\",";
    $query.= "\"$email\",";
    $query.= "\"$phone\",";
    $query.= "\"$training\",";
    $query.= "\"$norepairs\",";
    $query.= "\"$logo\",";
    $query.= "\"$repairtype\",";
    $query.= "\"$repairgroup\",";
    $query.= "NOW(),";
    $query.= "NOW(),";
    $query.= "$mode)";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $insertid = mysql_insert_id();
    $ref = "REP".$insertid;
    $licencenumber = "test".$insertid;

    $query = "UPDATE r_table SET ref = \"$ref\", licenseNumber=\"$licencenumber\" WHERE id = ".$insertid;

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo mysql_error();

    if (!$result)
        echo mysql_error();
    else
        return $ref;
```

Comment: In the event that it does exist, what happens then?

Comment: @Strawberry the apocalypse.

Comment: When it does or doesn't exist it still submits the form and the user can keep signing up using the same details over and over again and the database will create multiple entries with that information

Comment: Please ignore $email = $_POST['email'] ; that wasn't meant to be there

Comment: If you are wanting to check the database for a pre-existing user and prevent duplicate registrations, the solution will be deeper in the PHP code rather than the HTML or Javascript. Look through the file for something like `INSERT INTO ...` which will be the actual creation of the user in the database. It will probably be in the **signup.php** file.

Comment: So you want to inform the user that they've already registered?

Comment: The way the data is inserted into the database is via a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing like given below:

```
$query = "select * from `tablename` where `fieldname` = 'value'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_result = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_result > 0){
    //Value exist for field already
 }
```

Here `mysql_num_rows` return `number of rows of result of query`. So using this  You can check if company and email already exist or not.

Comment: Thank you that really helped, next question is that I got it to echo the following "Email does exist" and "Email doesn't exist" how do I instead of that being displayed stop the information being entered into the data if the  email exist and for it to return to the sign up page saying it exists.

Comment: hi , for redirect on email exist and display error..you can check `if($num_result > 0){header('Location:register.php?error=email'); }` And on `register.php` you can check `if(isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'email') {echo "Email exist";}` I hope it will be help you. thanks

Comment: @PhpNewbie - don't forget to tick this answer if it helped you. This is how we thank people for helping on Stack Overflow.